# Change attribute of JS widget direction=rtl into dir=rtl

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

Imagine there is a slider widget, like this.. 
`<SliderWidget width="500" height="360">`
Default direction is left-to-right,
 and it can be configured right-to-left, 
like this..
`<SliderWidget width="500" height="360" direction="rtl">`
It works, 
But I need to make the slider work rtl using this code..
like this..
`<SliderWidget width="500" height="360" dir="rtl">`
The slider plugin is SwiperJS and widget is built on ReactJS, but what I'm trying to do is make the widget work rtl if I gave `direction="rtl"` or `dir="rtl"`
How to achieve that?
Is there  a way to extend the `direction="rtl"` functionality to the attribute `dir="rtl"`?

Comment: Why don;t add some code. A FIDDLE will be great

Comment: so you want to change SwiperJS  which already developed ? if yes then currently in SwiperJS this,props.direction is used you can modified this.props.dir

Comment: ok..Thats a good starting point..Thank you Dhaval Patel

Comment: @AnoopChandran:I think that is the way you can achieve what you want so I think I have to make answer to my comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand very well your problem (why not simply use `direction`?), but you can always wrap a component and do whatever you want with it!

```
var MyWrapper = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    dir: React.PropTypes.oneOf(['rtl', 'ltr'])
  },

  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      dir: 'rtl'
    };
  }

  render: function() {
    return <SliderWidget width="500" height="360" direction={this.props.dir}/>;
  }
})
```

Read more about props here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the support..
 I was able to fix this by adding an "OR" expression to the "if" condition.
`getInitialState : function () {
      this.slides = [];
      var direction = 'ltr';
      var directionFactor = 1;
      if (this.props.direction === 'rtl' || this.props.dir === 'rtl') {
        direction = 'rtl';
        directionFactor = -1;
      }`